# Wildfly change email message size limit

Tags: email, smtp, wildfly, limit

I have an application running under Wildfly 9.0 which sends emails with attachments.
Some of these emails can have large attachments, when this happens I get an error message "552 5.2.3 Message size is over limit (15728640).
How can I increase Wildfly's maximum limit so that it can send larger attachments (e.g. 20mb)?
What parameters should I change on?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that the receiving mail server may also reject a message that is too large. If you really have that much data to transfer, you may be better off uploading it to some server and sending a link to that upload. Email was not designed to transfer large attachments; each binary attachment gets base64-encoded, which increases its size by factor 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to increment the value of Max header size and Max post size of the server.

From wildly console : Configuration:Subsystems > Subsystem:Undertow > Settings:HTTP

Select the HTTPListener anche change the value of the attributes